# While loop using strings and if statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, while-loop

Prompt for python program:
5.16 LAB: Password modifier
Many user-created passwords are simple and easy to guess. Write a program that takes a simple password and makes it stronger by replacing characters using the key below, and by appending "!" to the end of the input string.

i becomes 1
a becomes @
m becomes M
B becomes 8
s becomes $
Ex: If the input is:

mypassword
the output is:

Myp@$$word!
Hint: Python strings are immutable, but support string concatenation. Store and build the stronger password in the given password variable.
My code so far:

```
word = input()
password = ''
i = 0
while i < len(word):
```

I'm really just confused about changing certain characters in a string using a while loop. I was also trying to use if statements. While loops are hard for me understand. I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing fine. While loops have this format:

```
while (condition) == True: 
    # do this
```

In your case, you will want to put `i += 1` at then end of your loop so it doesn't go on forever, like this:

```
while i < len(word):
    # your code here

    i += 1 # this adds 1 to i
           # so eventually it will be equal to the length of word, ending the loop
```

As for `if` statements, you could try this:

```
while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == 'i':
        password += '1'
    
    i += 1
```

The if statements will only work on the values you want to change, so add an `else` statement to act as a default.

```
while i < len(word):
    if word[i] == 'i':
        password += '1'
    else:
        password += word[i]
    
    i += 1
```

Now, if you get a normal letter, like `h`, it will add it to the password.

Hope this helps you get started!

Comment: That helped a lot, I put the other if statements below the first one same formatting but using elif. Then I put a print statement after i += 1 saying print(password + '!') but when I use password as the input the output is just M@$$!

Comment: There you go. You can also use `else:` as a default for normal values. Have a nice day :).

Comment: I'll explain it in the answer :).